# Have D3 created buttons go to ellipsis

Tags: jquery-mobile, d3.js

I'm working with both the D3 library and the JQuery mobile library, and I run a function using D3 to create a series of buttons. When the webpage is shrunk, the text on these buttons goes off screen rather than going to ellipsis.
Here's the CSS I apply to the button:

```
    .ui-btn{
    overflow: hidden !important;
    white-space: nowrap !important;
    text-overflow: ellipsis !important;
}
```

D3 function:

`var Addedbuttons = d3.select("#TheButtons").selectAll("input")
                .data(data)
                .enter()
                .append('label')
                .text(function(d) { return d; })
                .append("input") 
                .attr("type", "radio")
                .attr("name","stmntRadio");`

This produces something along the lines of this:

[image: hidden]

where the text is still there, just hidden by the browser.
Another button that is styled correctly:
[image]

Comment: Seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/7fnzubbt/

Comment: Odd- I have to look more into what I override and what is still being formatted using JQmobile